# How to have one patch target multiple MSIs with different product codes?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installshield

I have 64-bit and 32-bit MSI releases of a product. In order for these releases to be treated as independent products so that for example, a 64-bit patch is not accidentally applied over 32-bit release MSI, and vice-versa, I assigned them different product codes. However, I would also like to be able to have one single patch applicable to both 32-bit and 64-bit - since all I patch is dlls and occasional exe.

I am currently building my uncompressed MSIs with InstallShield, however patching using WiX `PatchCreation`. I tried using

```
<TargetProductCode Id="*"/>
```

however that has not changed my behavior. Currently, I get `the upgrade patch cannot be installed..the program to be upgraded may be missing..` which makes sense.

What is the best practice to solve this problem? Should I just make the product codes the same between the two 32-bit and 64-bit releases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 32bit MSP can only patch a 32bit MSI.  Same for 64bit.  Yes, I would have different UpgradeCode and ProductCodes for the two installers.  If you want the patch to seem like 1 patch you can wrap it in a Burn bootstrapper.  The user will run the EXE and the correct patch will be applied.